# Maxima: converting a matrix equation into an assignment list

Tags: list, matrix, maxima

I want to evaluate an expression containing some symbols (given in the matrix `s`) whose values are given in the matrix `v`:

```
s: matrix([a,b,c]);
v: matrix([1,2,3]);
expr: a*b+c;
ev(expr,s=v); /* not working but gives the idea of the purpose */
```

How can I generate the correct assignment list `[a=1,b=2,c=3]` to be passed to `ev`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lists instead of matrices and create an adapter for [subst](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_6.html#IDX206)

```
(%i1) msubst(a, b, c):=block([L: map(lambda([a0, b0], a0=b0), a, b)], subst(L, c)) $
(%i2) s   : [a,b,c] $
(%i3) v   : [1,2,3] $
(%i4) msubst(s, v, a*b+c);
(%o4)                                  5
```

If you need to convert a matrix to a list

```
(%i1) m2l(M):=block([L: []], matrixmap(lambda([e], push(e, L)), M), L) $
(%i2) s: matrix([a,b,c]) $
(%i3) m2l(s);
(%o3)                              [c, b, a]
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to works, only I noticed that `m2l` function returns elements in reverse order. On Maxima mailing list I found another way to convert matrix to list which preserves order; `xreduce('append,args(M))`. You might want to take note and update your answer.

Answer (score 2):

*After much time I have posted a [much simpler solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54027560/694360). I suggest to use the new solution instead of the one below.*

On Maxima mailing list I found a way to generate the assignment list `[a=1,b=2,c=3]` to be passed to `ev`, using a much more general method (which allows to solve matrix equations `A=B` with unknonws in both sides -- never cooked an hot dog with a flame thrower?). Provided that a matrix can be converted to a list with the function

```
m2l(M):= xreduce('append,args(M)) $
```

the assignment list `[a=1,b=2,c=3]` to be passed to `ev` can be obtained by

```
assign_list(s,v):= algsys(xreduce('append, args(s-v)), m2l(s)) $
```

Therefore, given matrices `s`,`v` and expression `expr`, `expr` can be evaluated simply with

```
ev(expr,assign_list(s,v));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler solution:

```
m2l(M):= xreduce('append,args(M)) $
massl(A,B):= map("=",m2l(A),m2l(B)) $ /*massl stands for "matrix assignment list"*/
```

In our case `massl(s,v)` returns the assignment list `[a=1,b=2,c=3]`, as desired.